# Binding a method to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm having trouble binding a method to a gridview, could anybody help?. 
Basically, i'm returning a dataset in the `getAllPatients method` and then passing it to the asp.net page. When I go to load the page nothing happens.

Here is my method:

```
public DataSet GetAllPatients()
{
    //create objects
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlDataAdapter da = null;
    DataSet ds = null;
    string sql = string.Empty;

    //create sql string
    sql = "SELECT * FROM GP_Patient";

    //create connection
    conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GPConn"].ConnectionString);

    try
    {
        //create Data adapter
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);

        //fill dataset using data adapter
        da.Fill(ds, "Patients");
    }    
    catch
    {
        //don't do anything special, just let .Net handle it
    }    
    finally
    {
        // close connection and release data adapter
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Close();
            da.Dispose();
        }
    }

    //output the dataset
    return ds;
}
```

and here is my codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //create object
        Patient ptn = new Patient();

        //set datasource of control to objects method
        gridview1.DataSource = ptn.GetAllPatients();


        //bind
        gridview1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: An empty `catch` does not "let .NET handle it." Propagation/bubble up of the exception stops at a catch and w/out a (re)throw, normal execution continues. I suppose it's possible to get an exception and not know it in this case.

Comment: Wheres the gridview? the AutogeneratingColumns is equals true?

Comment: yes the AutogeneratingColumns is now set to true but doesnt make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue with thanks to my lecturer at SHU.

The problem was that I was creating the dataAdapter:

```
 //create Data adapter
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
```

But wasnt creating the dataset, like I should here:

```
 //create Data Set
        ds = new DataSet("patients");
```

therefore it was blank

this link was useful too http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314145

Answer (score 1):

Just set:

```
gridView1.DataMember = "Patients";
```

You can still return the full set (you might have more tables later, right?) and just let DataMember dictate which to display in-grid.

Comment: The DataMember will be "Patients" looking this Fill function!

Comment: @DonBoitnott thanks for your help but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: For the sake of thoroughness...the DataMember property should be set _before_ the DataSource and DataBind() calls.